# Align image to left of heading - html

Tags: android, html, image, alignment

I am making an android app and this html file is located in the assets folder.
I want to align a vertical straight line to the left of a heading, much like what is done in the yahoo news digest app. See Screenshot here http://bit.ly/1BRljIX .

I tried using the code below:

```
<img style="display: ;" src="sidebar_leader.png" width="2%"/>
<h3 style="display: inline;">We want sport to be safe, we want sport to be fun and we want to ensure that no matter what sport young people are involved in, that it takes place in the spirit of 'fair play'.</h3>
```

However this just aligned the image with the first line of the heading can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just scrap the image completely and use `border-left` with a bit of `padding-left` to space things out.

This way you'll make less requests to the hosting server (as you won't be needing the image file anymore) and your page will be more lightweight, ergo more mobile friendly.

Using a CSS stylesheet, as opposed to inline styles like you're using, the code would be as follows:

```css
h3 {
  border-left: 4px solid #3BB6FE;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h3>We want sport to be safe, we want sport to be fun and we want to ensure that no matter what sport young people are involved in, that it takes place in the spirit of 'fair play'.</h3>
```

Using a stylesheet has its benefits as you can assign a style to all your `h3` elements in one place and, should you need to update the design at a later date, you will only need to change it in one place, instead of trying to find every instance of that particular style in your application.

Should you however wish to continue down the inline-styles route, your code will be as follows:

```
<h3 style="border-left: 4px solid #3BB6FE; padding-left: 10px;">We want sport to be safe, we want sport to be fun and we want to ensure that no matter what sport young people are involved in, that it takes place in the spirit of 'fair play'.</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/3gjzcrv4/2/)

Try this

```
<img style="float:left;" src="sidebar_leader.png" width="2%" height="100px"/>
<h3 style="float:left;width:98%;">We want sport to be safe, we want sport to be fun and we want to ensure that no matter what sport young people are involved in, that it takes place in the spirit of 'fair play'.</h3>
```

I've used `float:left;` instead of `display:inline;`..I've given a width of 98% which is actually 100%-(width of img)